# Azure AD B2C - cacheLocation change from sessionStorage to localStorage

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-ad-b2c, msal

I'm working with a React Single Page Application that uses Azure ADB2C for user sign-ups and sign-ins.

The application is already in Production serving customers.

We are using @msal/browser & @msal/react packages. The cache set up is currently `sessionStorage`.

We are looking into changing that to `localStorage`.

Is there any pitfalls or issues to be vary off for this change?

Thanks,
Anand.

Would there any be problems with already signed in users?

Answer (score 0):

*I tried the following code for login and logout with **localStorage** in Azure AD B2C using @msal/browser and @msal/react packages.*

**Code :**

***index.js :***

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { MsalProvider } from '@azure/msal-react';
import App from './App';
import { config } from './Config';

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication({
  auth: {
    clientId: config.appId,
    redirectUri: config.redirectUri,
    authority: config.authority,
    knownAuthorities: config.knownAuthorities,
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
  },
});

const root = document.getElementById('root');

const render = (Component) => {
  ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
        <Component />
      </MsalProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
  );
};
render(App);
```

***AuthButton.js :***

```js
import React from 'react';
import { config } from './Config';

function AuthButton({ msalInstance }) {
  const login = async () => {
    try {
      await msalInstance.loginPopup({
        scopes: config.scopes,
        prompt: 'login',
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={login}>Login</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default AuthButton;
```

***App.js :***

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';
import AuthButton from './AuthButton';

function App() {
  const { accounts, instance } = useMsal();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>MSAL React App</h1>
        {accounts.length === 0 ? (
          <AuthButton msalInstance={instance} />
        ) : (
          <div>
            <p>Welcome, {accounts[0].name}</p>
            <button onClick={() => instance.logout()}>Logout</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

***Config.js :***

```js
export const config = {
    appId: '<client_ID>',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',
    scopes: ['openid', 'profile','user.read'],
    authority: 'https://<b2c-tenant>.b2clogin.com/<your-b2c-tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>',
    knownAuthorities: ['https://<b2c-tenant>.b2clogin.com/<your-b2c-tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>'],
  };
```

I added the following URL to the app authentication as a Single-page application:

> http://localhost:3000

[image]

I added the scope **[openid, profile, user.read]** in the app **API permission**.

[image]

**Output :**

It ran successfully as below,

[image]

**Output at browser :**

I got the below output at the browser with the output **URL**. I clicked on the Login button and logged in with my Azure AD B2C email details.

[image]

I successfully logged in and got the welcome page.

[image]

Comment: Hi Dasari, Thanks for the effort you put into responding to this question. My question was whether there is any implication when moving from sessionStorage to localStorage. Not starting out a fresh application on localStorage?